# Springs and Hooke's law, entry level college physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

A person with $80 kg$ enters a car. The springs are compressed $1.2 cm$. The total mass (car + person) is $900kg$. What's the caractheristic frequency of the car's oscillation with the person inside?

Solution is $1,36 Hz$, but I don't know how to get there.

Also, I'm not sure about what equations I should be using for this problem, since I've asked around my classmates and noone is really sure either. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you know about resonance of a mass on a spring? If I load a spring with 800 N, and it displaces by 1.2 cm, can you compute $k$, the spring constant? If you have spring constant and mass, can you compute frequency? Tell us where you get stuck. "I don't have a clue" doesn't work, with homework questions on this site.

Comment: Well, you only need 2 formulae for this. One is Hooke's Law the other one is the formula for a harmonic oscillators characteristic frequency $\omega$, which you can then convert into a frequency $f$. I get the solution you wrote.

As a general rule, homework and exercise questions like this should show a jab at it. What do you know so far?

Comment: What do you get for the spring constant?

Comment: I knew I had to use some equations, but I couldn't pierce them together. For example, $ F = -kx $, I was not aware that $F$ would be just the weight of the person, I was considering person + car. This is fairly new and I'm trying to work out how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: i keep getting 4.55. I treated it as one spring. So k=900*g/0.012) w= root(k/900). Then f = w/(2*pi). I keep getting quadruple the answer, even when looking at each spring individually. Maybe there's something wrong

Comment: Well, aparently, when you use $F = -kx $, your $F$ can't be the total weight, it has to be the weight that made the displacement. It was the 80kg person that made the 0.012m displacement,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the frequency, use Hooke's law, F=kx to find k ( spring constant ) and here x is the extension (1.2 cm to be converted to meters ) and F is the extra weight ( due to 80 kg person) equal to about 800 N.
Now the**Time period** of a mass-spring system is given by:
$$ T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$
Thus the frequency is then 1/T

Note: Here the m is the total mass of person and car (900 kg) and k is the spring constant

Comment: Total mass is 900 kg, but it works! Now a question, something that was bothering me, shouldn't we have 4 springs, since it's a car? Even if the frequency is the same considering 1 or 4 springs, is the resolution different? I assume I can't just use Hooke's law, because I think that just works for 1 spring.

Comment: yes, 4 springs will quarter the extension. Or equivalently, the spring constant quadruples

Comment: because the individual extension is given, we need to work out the force on one spring which is one quarter of the total force

Comment: Yes, I get the same answer if I assume the weight of the person is evenly distributed by the 4 springs - making $F = 200 N$ and total mass $m = 900/4$

Comment: Yes, I corrected it to 900 kg, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hookes law (F=-kx) to find the spring constant, and then use the formula for frequency as a function of spring constant and mass. (f = 1/2pi * sqrt(k/m))